# fileUpload and update in IE

Tags: primefaces

I am using PF RC1, JSF 2.0 with GF3.1

I have fileupload control of PF to upload a file and then display the uploaded file in the datatable below. This works fine in firefox but in IE the uploaded file does not show in the bottom datatable. I am also saving the uploaded file in db which does gets saved after file is uploaded, it just does not show in bottom datatable in IE. I am using IE 9.0

Is this a PF bug that fileupload (update) does not work in IE?

Here is the code -

```
<h:form id="myForm">
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{myController.handleFileUpload}"
              label="Upload" mode="advanced" multiple="true" auto="true"
              process="@this" update="myForm:uploadTbl"
              />  
<p:dataTable value="#{myController.displayUploadedList}" 
             var="item" id="uploadTbl"
             rows="5">
             <p:column>
                      <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
             </p:column>
</p:datatable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Why are you using `process=@this`?  Remove that and see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used p:remoteCommand and onComplete of fileupload called the remoteCommand which in turn updated the datatable displaying the uploaded filed. Now it works in IE also.